# Downloaded JNLP file launches automatically sometimes

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat, java-web-start, jnlp

I have two solaris machines, and both the machines have identical tomcat serever installed. Now when i request a URL on these servers a JNLP file is downloaded. But the behavior is not consistent.

When sending the request on one server by IE, the browser shows a user prompt whether to download the file or not and then the user had to launch the file by double clicking the downloaded JNLP file.

On the other server for the same request, the browser downloads the file without a user prompt and launches the JNLP file automatically. (No double click required).

Can anybody please tell me why the behaviour is not same. And how can i make the behavior consistent.

I have checked the MIME type mapping at both the servers at conf/web.xml
Both are same and correct as per the oracle specification.
I also checked the Java Control Panel Mime allocation for the JNLP, and it is set to prompt user.